# Is there a way to declare dependencies inside a u-sql database project?

Tags: u-sql

## Introduction and problem description

We are developing a Datalake Analytics solution. We have been using regular U-SQL projects, which are good, but you are left having to work out the packaging and deployment.
So we gave a try to U-SQL Database projects. In theory they are far better and well suited for what we want.
We created a database project that contains so far:

- Some Table Types
- Some TVFs that receive and / or return some of those table types
- Some Procedures that receive and / or return some of those table types

It builds from visual studio, and I can see the `usqldbpack` output. So far, so good. When I try to deploy it, it always fails with the cryptic message

```
Deployment failed with Deployment failed with exception 'Failed to deploy DDL script, SDK helper app return failure '-1'' -> Failed to deploy DDL script, SDK helper app return failure '-1'
```

Then I checked the log, and I see things like

```
*** Error : (9,59) 'Type 'DatabaseProject1.dbo.MyTableType' does not exist.'
*** Compile failed !
```

Then I saw the `ddl.usql` generated by the project, and the Table Type is below the functions that use it. So it is no wonder that it fails.

So I guess there should be a way to let the project know that a TVF is depending on a Table Type, so that it can build the script right.

Is there a way?

## Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create inside Visual Studio a U-SQL Database Project
2. Create a Table Type, named MyTableType, with the following code

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS [dbo].[MyTableType]
       AS TABLE
       (
           [id] string,
           [name] string
       );
```

3. Create a Procedure, named MyProcedure, with the following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS [dbo].[MyProcedure](@table dbo.MyTableType)  
AS  
BEGIN 
    OUTPUT @table
    TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/DDL/Procedure/MyTable.csv"  
    USING Outputters.Csv();    
END;
```

4. Build the solution. It will build without any issue
5. Deploy the database, it will fail
6. Check the log, it will say

```
*** Error : (9,59) 'Type 'DatabaseProject1.dbo.MyTableType' does not exist.'
*** Compile failed !
```